# Alternative to fs.readdirSync large directory directory in Node

Tags: node.js

I have a single directory with a few million json files in it. I ultimately want to iterate over each file in the directory, read it, do something with the information and then write something into a database.

My script works perfectly when I use a test directory with a few hundred files.  However, it stalls when I use the real directory.  I strongly believe that I have pinpointed the problem to the use of:

```
fs.readdirSync('my dir path')
```

Converting this to the Async function would not help anything since I need the file names before anything else can happen anyways.  However, my belief is that this operation hangs because it simply "takes too long" for it to read the entire directory.

For reference here is a broader portion of the function:

```
function traverseFS(){
    var path = 'my dir name and path';
    var files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    for (var i in files) {  
        path + '/' + files[i];
        var fileText = fs.readFileSync(currentFile,'utf8');
        var json= JSON.parse(fileText);
        if(json)
            // do something
    }
}
```

My question is either:

1. Is there something I can do get this to work using readdirSync?
2. Is there another operation I should be using?

Comment: why do you need synchronous reading?  Is it possible to relax that requirement?  Is it possible to split up the data you need to read at once? Could you namespace your directories with a prefix or a date or something?  so that the path is only composed of directories, and not of all one million files?

Comment: I don't need synchronous reading but like I said making it async wouldn't help.  I would really rather not split up the data.  It's sort of a chicken or the egg problem since manipulating that many files in windows is hell.  These are great ideas.  But they don't really address my two specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either use a child process (easiest) that creates a directory listing and parse that *or* write your own streamable binding to `scandir()` (on *nix) and/or whatever the equivalent is on Windows and use that. For the latter, you may want to use the libuv code ([*nix](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/c02176a23062fbde2273579ee641aa47f35d6778/src/unix/fs.c#L364-L416), [Windows](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/7dfa54d6f8f2c5544829828b9da1dbf1aa77963e/src/win/fs.c#L821-L1031)) as a guide.